# Files that are needed to build a Visual Studio solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation

I want to share my Visual Studio solution with someone else but I'm not sure what are the minimum files besides the classes are needed for them to compile on their end. I have 3 projects in my solution.

Comment: If you're not sure, then share everything to the person.  Also, we would need more information, such as what kind of application you're trying to share.  Is it a Web application? Desktop application? Mobile apps(such as Windows Phone, Android, iOS)? Is it a Console Application?

Comment: it is a console application sorry.

Comment: Then, among the classes, make sure you include the default file program.cs (since you're a beginner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the usual ".gitignore" file that is used to avoid commiting useless or generated files, leaving your solution with only the files you need to compile properly.

You can get it there for example : https://www.gitignore.io/api/visualstudio

You can also clean your solution (Build -> Clean Solution) to delete tempory, built and generated files. But the gitignore is more complete :)